# jquery ajax open a link page into another page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I ve created three fiddles for easy to understand:

`index.html` - [Index Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erL0t3s4/1/)

`helpFiles.html` - [Help Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezjr9m1z/)

`products.html` - [Products](http://jsfiddle.net/7nkrbsbq/1/)

in `Index.html` When i click `Products read more` link it should open `helpFiles.html` page(initially `helpFiles.html` contains no data having main div with id "#helpFiles") with `Products.html` page content should insert into `#helpFiles` div.

Pls help me out with sample code and sorry for my english.

Comment: Seems like your solution may be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file. Take a look, it talks about using JQuery to perform such a process.

Comment: i am getting confused like in index.html page ill click any link(read more...) which ll navigate to helpfiles.html. in helpfiles.html how will i know that i click on particular link like products item. do i need to give different ids to index.html items.? with ids how ill navigate. pls help me

Comment: you could pass the productname through the url and access it in the 2nd page

Comment: as i am very  new to ajax, can u pls prepare answer with code. so that i can mark as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **localStorage**

The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

In your **index.html** you could replace your

```
<a href="HelpFiles.html" class="readMore">Read more...</a>
```

with

```
<a href="HelpFiles.html?page=products" class="readMore">Read more...</a>
```

Add this script on the top of this page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".itemContent .readMore").click(function(){
        var imgName = $(this).parent().parent().find("img").attr("src");
        url = $(this).attr("href"); //Gets the url from the anchor tag clicked
        var page = url.split("?page=");
        localStorage.setItem("pageName", page[1]);
        localStorage.setItem("imageName", imgName);
    });
 });
</script>
```

In your **helpfiles.html** you have to add the following script on top

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var pageName = localStorage.getItem("pageName"); 
       var imagepath =localStorage.getItem("imageName");
       $("#helpFiles").load(pageName+".html"); 
});
</script>
```

Hope this might give you an idea mate.. :)

**FYI**

[localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: that works gr8. and one more small doubt pls help me with this as well.
how can i pass index.html page clicked image to helpfiles.html page..?

Comment: you could try passing the imagename as well through the url

Comment: can u pls provide me the code as well pls and provide me the best tutorials as well.

Comment: and how can i use "imagepath" variable?
i tried like this but no hope
$("#item-image").load(imagepath);
where as #item-image is from products page

Comment: try `$("#item-image img").attr("src",imagepath)`

Comment: Good solution. Comments. (1) You can simply pass the `.html` extension with the filename and omit that addition to the string (either approach works). (2) To avoid CORS issues, run in a webserver (e.g., on localhost: `http-server --cors -p 8081 /your_path`). (3) The `.itemContent` class appears to be an orphan: delete it. (4) Tested 2023-09 with JQuery 3.5.1 (standard web link to library; `... crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" ...`. (5) In my use case, no image, so I commented out the `img` code.